# Sql: How to add multiple entries in sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Kindly advice how to execute multiple commands in 1 go for adding entries in sql table.

```
mysql> desc detailed;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id                  | roll(5)       | YES  | 1   | NULL    |       |
| Name                | varchar(896)  | NO   | 2   |         |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Expected

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id                  | roll(5)       | YES  | 1   | NULL    |       |
| Name                | varchar(896)  | NO   | 2   |         |       |
| Value1              | varchar(102)  | Yes  |     | NULL    |       |
| Value2              | varchar(102)  | Yes  |     | NULL    |       |
| Value3              | varchar(102)  | Yes  |     | NULL    |       |
| Value4              | varchar(102)  | Yes  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


ALTER TABLE detailed ADD `Value1` varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE detailed ADD `Value2` varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE detailed ADD `Value3` varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE detailed ADD `Value4` varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL;
-- and it's till 50 Value so very time consuming.
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have a suspicion, that something is wrong with your DB structure. Why do you need so many similar columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the mysql documentation you can add multiple columns with one `alter table` command.

> You can issue multiple ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE clauses in a single ALTER TABLE statement, separated by commas. This is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per ALTER TABLE statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE
    detailed
ADD Value1 varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD Value2 varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD Value3 varchar(102) DEFAULT NULL;
```